# Find UserName in Different Table Using UserId

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019-express

I have two tables. One is the `userInfo` table another is the `income expenses` table, This table has multiple columns. I want to summation these columns using `GROUP BY` and try to show `TotalIncome`, `Totalexpenses` and `userName` that it.

Here is the query:

```
    select Pa.LoginID, Sum(CB.AFDC+CB.ChildSupport+CB.FoodStamps+CB.OtherIncome+CB.WagesSalary+CB.VeteransBenefit+CB.SocialSecurity+CB.Retirement+CB.GeneraAssistance) as TotalIncome ,
            
    Sum(CB.WaterSewer+CB.Transportation+CB.HouseRent+CB.FoodCost+CB.Electricity+CB.DoctorVisit+CB.ChildCare+CB.CarPayment+CB.OtherExpense) as TotalExpences
    
     from Client_BurnOuts CB
            
        Join PatientPortalLogins Pa on CB.PatientApplicationId = Pa.PatientApplicationId 
            group by Pa.PatientApplicationId
```

I can get only the total summation different used:

```
    select PatientApplicationId, Sum(AFDC+ChildSupport+FoodStamps+OtherIncome+WagesSalary+VeteransBenefit+SocialSecurity+Retirement+GeneraAssistance) as TotalIncome ,
    Sum(WaterSewer+Transportation+HouseRent+FoodCost+Electricity+DoctorVisit+ChildCare+CarPayment+OtherExpense) as TotalExpences
    from Client_BurnOuts
    group by PatientApplicationId
```

Comment: Add username column in Group By clause and Select list.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand

Comment: In which table the username column is available?

Comment: PatientPortalLogins this table contains all user information. And Client_BurnOuts table has a PatientApplicationId as a foreign key, I try to hold value using foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT Pa.LoginID, TotalIncome , TotalExpences
FROM
    (SELECT PatientApplicationId, 
        SUM(AFDC+ChildSupport+FoodStamps+OtherIncome+WagesSalary+VeteransBenefit+SocialSecurity+Retirement+GeneraAssistance) AS TotalIncome ,
        SUM(WaterSewer+Transportation+HouseRent+FoodCost+Electricity+DoctorVisit+ChildCare+CarPayment+OtherExpense) AS TotalExpences
    FROM Client_BurnOuts
    GROUP BY PatientApplicationId) AS CB
JOIN PatientPortalLogins PA ON CB.PatientApplicationId = PA.PatientApplicationIdl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate the values grouped by PatientApplicationId from Client_BurnOuts and then join with user table to get user details. Please try the below query.

```
SELECT Pa.PatientApplicationId, Pa.UserName, Summary.TotalIncome, Summary.TotalExpences
    (
    SELECT CB.PatientApplicationId ,Sum(CB.AFDC+CB.ChildSupport+CB.FoodStamps+CB.OtherIncome+CB.WagesSalary+CB.VeteransBenefit+CB.SocialSecurity+CB.Retirement+CB.GeneraAssistance) AS TotalIncome 
        ,Sum(CB.WaterSewer+CB.Transportation+CB.HouseRent+CB.FoodCost+CB.Electricity+CB.DoctorVisit+CB.ChildCare+CB.CarPayment+CB.OtherExpense) AS TotalExpences
    FROM Client_BurnOuts CB 
    GROUP BY CB.PatientApplicationId
) AS Summary            
INNER JOIN PatientPortalLogins Pa ON Summary.PatientApplicationId = Pa.PatientApplicationId
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Keep up the good work